# Monitor Failovercluster roles with Icinga2

Tags: monitoring, nagios, failovercluster, icinga

I'm using `Icinga2` with `NSClient++`

I have a `PowerShell` check for certain cluster roles which is installed on every `cluster node`.
Should a cluster role fail, all `cluster nodes` would send out identical notifications which will result in a lot of spam for just one actual service problem.

Only installing the check on one cluster node is no option as it would produce a single point of failure for role monitoring: A failing cluster node should not affect the cluster roles (aside from a short timeout) but I would not be able to check any cluster role as soon as it's down.

Is it possible to assign a `service` to a `hostgroup` in a way that only one notification will be sent if this service fails?

Comment: Can you post your service that monitoring that hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having the check itself check if he should report a problem as critical (service on the node itself failed) or warning/ok (service on another node failed).